# Qucikblox IOS SDK Creating a chat room - Room is locked?

Tags: chat, quickblox

I'm adding the Quickblox chat API to my app and I am able to view chat rooms just fine. 
But when trying a create a chatroom, I get a message saying

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="reliefme_23@muc.chat.quickblox.com" to="158737-1588@chat.quickblox.com/tigase-40290" type="groupchat"><body>Welcome! You created new Multi User Chat Room. Room is locked now. Configure it please!</body></message>
```

here's my code

```
-(IBAction)createChatRoom:(id)sender
{
    if([[QBChat instance] isLoggedIn])
    {
         [[QBChat instance] createOrJoinRoomWithName:self.chatroom_txt.text membersOnly:NO persistent:YES];
    }


}



- (void)chatRoomDidEnter:(QBChatRoom *)room
{
    NSLog(@"room %@",room);
}
```

Comment: So, is chatRoomDidEnter method calling?

Comment: No, chatRoomDidEnter is not being called

Comment: I have a list of chat rooms in tableView, if i create a chat room after the chat rooms have been  loaded it works fine. But if i first go into a chat room, then leave the chat room and then try to create a chat room, the createChatRoomForTopic block does not get called, (Im using your ChatService Class from the chat sample)